# Change background on li element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing I want to do is when a user clicks on a link, the background should change to Indicate which Link the user has clicked on. I'm trying to do this with jQuery:

```js
$('.menuLink').click(function() {
  var img = $(this).find('img');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("#" + id).addClass('activeLink');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```css
.menuLinks li {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #004f80;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
}
.menuLinks li:hover {
  background-color: #006eb3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuLinks li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.activeLink {
  color: #004f80;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menuLinks">
  <li class="menuLink" id="tillstandshavare">Link1</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="stationer">Lnk2</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="formular">Link3</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="fragor">Link4</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="installningar">Link5</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm attaching the activeLink class. But the background are never changed. I think this is because of menuLinks is not overrided.

Comment: Isn't `var id = $(this).attr('id'); $("#" + id)...` the same as `$(this)..`?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks: That does not help me. :)

Comment: That's why it was just a comment. xD

Comment: @Rory his answer is correct, if you would like to read more about this specific topic, I advice this article: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `.activeLink` class is not specific enough for it to override the default `.menuLink li` styling. You need to make it more specific. Also note that you can use `this` to reference the clicked element instead of building the id selector string manually. Try this:

```js
$('.menuLink').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('activeLink');
});
```

```css
.menuLinks li {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 115px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #004f80;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
}
.menuLinks li:hover {
  background-color: #006eb3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menuLinks li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menuLinks li.activeLink {
  color: #004f80;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menuLinks">
  <li class="menuLink" id="tillstandshavare">Link1</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="stationer">Lnk2</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="formular">Link3</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="fragor">Link4</li>
  <li class="menuLink" id="installningar">Link5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help